# Django Project Install error (The conflict is caused by: The user requested asgiref==3.2.5 django 3.1.14 depends on asgiref<4 and >=3.2.10)

Tags: python, django, conflict

When I try to install `requirements.txt` this error happened.

This is `requirements.txt`

```
asgiref==3.2.5
astroid==2.3.3
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
defusedxml==0.6.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.1.14
django-allauth==0.41.0
django-crispy-forms==1.9.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.9
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
oauthlib==3.1.0
Pillow==9.0.1
pylint==2.4.4
PySocks==1.7.1
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.23.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
stripe==2.43.0
```

[image]

***This error says***

*ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 8) and asgiref==3.2.5 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
The conflict is caused by:
The user requested asgiref==3.2.5
django 3.1.14 depends on asgiref<4 and >=3.2.10
To fix this you could try to:

1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
   ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your `requirements.txt` remove the `asgiref==3.2.5` line.

Django needs `asgiref > 4` but you are forcing to install `3.2.5`, that's why there is a conflict occurring.

Comment: Can I simply change asgiref version in my `requirements.txt` file ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that as well.

Comment: But the latest version is `asgiref 3.5.2` do they have a newer version than this ? I mean `asgiref > 4` or something like that ????